# Подключение геймпада к WPF приложению (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, sharpdx, sharpdevelop

Добрейшего времени суток.

Меня заинтересовала возможность взаимодействовать с приложением посредством **геймпада**, но вот беда.

Я вычитал [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39109609/how-to-use-xbox-one-controller-in-c-sharp-application), что лучший вариант подключения геймпада к приложению, это **SharpDX**.

Только вот непонятна лишь одна часть. Там предлагают использовать `using SharpDX.XInput;`, но SharpDevelop v5 уведомляет, что у **ShardDX** отсутствует **XInput**.

SharpDX я скачивал напрямую, [без использования NuGet](https://nuget.info/packages/SharpDX/4.2.0).

Comment: Используйте более старую версию где есть `XInput`

Comment: А в какой более старой версии есть XInput?

Comment: Не знаю, можете скачивать с nuget разные версии и смотреть есть ли XInput. Ну или гляньте https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX/releases, судя по релизам и ссылки которую вы привели на SO (там ответы 2016 года), можно скачать какую-то версию из 2016 (3.0.2 или 3.1.0)

Comment: Судя по репозиторию `SharpDX.XInput` вполне себе присуствует. Поставьте через NuGet и перепроверьте, быть может что-то упустили.

Comment: Я сомневаюсь, что в SharpDevelop имеется NuGet установщик.

Comment: В Visual Studio `Install-Package SharpDX -Version 4.2.0` возвращает ошибку 404

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку ответ не был дан, и NuGet лично не справлялся с установкой (Банально не мог найти страницу с пакетом) я додумался до такого варианта.

Решение:

- Ввести в поиск `SharpDX`;
- Выбрать из результатов `SharpDX.XInput`;
- Нажать `Open in NuGet Package Explorer`;
- Скачать `.dll` файл необходимой версии (в моем случае `net4.5`);
- Добавить скаченный `SharpDX.XInput.dll` файл в ссылки проекта;